# How can I count the number of substring entry by using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm starting with input data like this

```
email                               country_code
12345kinglobito94@hotmail.com           RU
12345arturdyikan6211@gmail.com          RU
12345leonardosebastianld.20@gmail.com   PE
12345k23156876vs@hotmail.com            RU
12345jhuillcag@hotmail.com              PE
12345ergasovaskazon72@gmail.com         RU
12345myrzadaevajrat@gmail.com           RU
12345filomena@hotmail.com               BR
12345jppicotajose20@hotmail.com         BR
...                                    ...
```

Which when printed appears as this:

```
                                      email country_code
0            12345kinglobito94@hotmail.com           RU
1           12345arturdyikan6211@gmail.com           RU
2    12345leonardosebastianld.20@gmail.com           PE
3             12345k23156876vs@hotmail.com           RU
4               12345jhuillcag@hotmail.com           PE
5          12345ergasovaskazon72@gmail.com           RU
6            12345myrzadaevajrat@gmail.com           RU
7                12345filomena@hotmail.com           BR
8          12345jppicotajose20@hotmail.com           BR
...                                                 ...
```

Grouping is simple enough:

```
country_code
AR     21
BR    340
PE    198
RU    402
US     39
Name: email, dtype: int64
```

But i want to count how many hotmail & gmail domains in each country

Comment: [See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Extract the domains using regex and then use groupby().size() i.e

```
df['domains'] = df['email'].str.extract('@(.*?)\.',expand=False)

                                email country_code  domains
0          12345kinglobito94@hotmail.com           RU  hotmail
1         12345arturdyikan6211@gmail.com           RU    gmail
2  12345leonardosebastianld.20@gmail.com           PE    gmail
3           12345k23156876vs@hotmail.com           RU  hotmail
4             12345jhuillcag@hotmail.com           PE  hotmail
5        12345ergasovaskazon72@gmail.com           RU    gmail
6          12345myrzadaevajrat@gmail.com           RU    gmail
7              12345filomena@hotmail.com           BR  hotmail
8        12345jppicotajose20@hotmail.com           BR  hotmail

df.groupby(["country_code","domains"]).size()

country_code  domains
BR            hotmail    2
PE            gmail      1
              hotmail    1
RU            gmail      3
              hotmail    2
dtype: int64
```

If you dont want an additional column you can also do

```
df.groupby(["country_code",df['email'].str.extract('@(.*?)\.',expand=False)]).size()
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `str.replace()` but i think @Dark's variant is more idiomatic:

```
In [17]: (df.assign(domain=df['email'].str.replace(r'.*?@(.*?)\.\w+', r'\1'))
    ...:    .groupby(['country_code', 'domain'])['email']
    ...:    .count()
    ...:    .reset_index(name='count'))
    ...:
Out[17]:
  country_code   domain  count
0           BR  hotmail      2
1           PE    gmail      1
2           PE  hotmail      1
3           RU    gmail      3
4           RU  hotmail      2
```